# Calculate tax value from gross and tax percentage

Tags: percentage, finance

I need to calculate the actual tax value when only the gross value and tax percentage is known.

The basic formula to calculate the gross amount:

Gross = Net * 1+Vat
Tax = Net * Vat

```
Example:
Net = 152.75 USD
Vat = 7 %

Gross = 152.75 * 1.07 = 163.44 USD
Tax = 152.75 * 0.07 = 10.69 USD

Proof: 
Gross - Tax = Net
163.44 USD - 10.69 USD = 152.75 USD
```

However, in my case I only have Gross and Vat and need to get the Tax value in a single multiplication.

The current approach is the following:

Tax = Gross − (Gross / 1+Vat)

```
Example:
Tax = 163.44 USD - (163.44 USD / 1.07) = 10.69 USD
```

Question:

How can I get the Tax value **with a simple multiplication**, without the need of a subtraction.

Comment: Tax = Gross * Vat  / 100 +Vat. Example Tax = (163.44 * 7)/ 107. Without substraction vat should be constant

Comment: Exactly! Thanks for the solution @PranavanSp

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about programming or programming tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, posted in the comment by @PranavanSp:

**Gross to Tax**

> Tax = Gross * Vat / (1 + Vat)

Example:
   Tax = 163.44 * 0.07 / 1.07 = 10.69

---

**Gross to Net**

And for completeness, also the net calculation:

> Net = Gross / (1 + Vat)

Example:
   Net = 163.44 / 1.07 = 152.75

Comment: You should use () in your answer to make it correct, i.e `Net = Gross / (1 + Vat)`